# Is it true that if $n = 2^k$ for some integer $k\geq 1,$ then $\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}$ is an even number?

Tags: number-theory, combinations

> **Question:** Fix a natural number $n.$
>   Is it true that if $n = 2^k$ for some integer $k\geq 1,$ then 
>   $$\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}$$ 
>   is an even number?

Note that $\frac{n}{2}$ is always an integer, so the combination is defined.

Recall that to calculate $\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}},$ we calculation a fraction with numerator $\frac{n}{2}$ numbers starting with $n$ and then decrease by $1,$ and denominator $\frac{n}{2}$ starting with $1$ and then increase by $1.$

I notice that $n$ in numerator always cancels with $2 \times \frac{n}{2}$ at the denominator, so the number of even numbers for numerator is more than in denominator. 
However, I do not take into account the power of $2$ in both numerator and denominator.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: $$2^{2n}={2n\choose n}+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{2n\choose k}$$

Answer (score 2):

For any integer $m\ge1$,
$$\binom{2m}{m}=\binom{2m-1}{m-1}+\binom{2m-1}m=2\binom{2m-1}{m-1}$$
is even.